# adb devices not showing

Tags: android, adb, appium, usb-debugging

I am new to Appium. Developer option and USB debugging are ON on my android device but the node.js and cmd doesn't print devices connected it just prints "List of devices attached" as shown in the image. What should I do? Also, I have tried to restart my system to resolve the issue.

[Node.js snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Pmw.png)

Comment: Does your Usb(Phone is detected for data transfer or any other) installed in the system. Are you able to find the device connected in the driver section.

Comment: you might have to accept the RSA fingerprint popup on the phone if this is the first time you are connecting this phone to this pc